# remove padding-left before p tag inside li

Tags: html, css

I am trying to styling `ol` list. I almost performed all requirements, but I cannot to remove `padding-left: 50px` before `p` tag inside `li`.

I just need to  set `padding-left: 50px` for the first line of `li`, but it sets `padding-left: 50px` for `p` also.

Please see the example: https://jsfiddle.net/8gm4zmc4/

As I understand `::after` for `li` will not help to fix that.

Please advise how to set `padding-left: 50px` for the first line of `li` or remove `padding-left: 50px` before `p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `p` element is nested inside your `li` element, so everything inside the `li` will also move to the right when you set a padding. You can solve this by setting a negative `margin-left` on your `.purchase-way__text` like:

```css
.purchase-way__list {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  counter-reset: foo;
}
.purchase-way__item {
  position: relative;
  counter-increment: li;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: ProximaNovaBold, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 0.833;
  color: #01b04c;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.purchase-way__item::before {
  content: counter(li);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -6px;
  background: #01b04c;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  font-family: ProximaNovaRegular, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
.purchase-way__text {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: ProximaNovaRegular, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.714;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="purchase-way__list">
  <li class="purchase-way__item">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <p class="purchase-way__text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nec molestie tellus. Nam et neque a lectus vestibulum porttitor quis non nunc. Aenean luctus eu lorem id lobortis. Integer a tortor orci. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit. Pellentesque ac est vel eros facilisis feugiat. Donec ornare ligula non fringilla hendrerit. In consequat faucibus ligula, ac venenatis velit dictum vitae. In in condimentum ex. Nulla lorem erat, fermentum non quam in, commodo molestie lacus.
      Praesent feugiat sit amet lectus nec mattis.
    </p>
  </li>
  <li class="purchase-way__item">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <p class="purchase-way__text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nec molestie tellus. Nam et neque a lectus vestibulum porttitor quis non nunc. Aenean luctus eu lorem id lobortis. Integer a tortor orci. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit. Pellentesque ac est vel eros facilisis feugiat. Donec ornare ligula non fringilla hendrerit. In consequat faucibus ligula, ac venenatis velit dictum vitae. In in condimentum ex. Nulla lorem erat, fermentum non quam in, commodo molestie lacus.
      Praesent feugiat sit amet lectus nec mattis.
    </p>
  </li>
  <li class="purchase-way__item">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <p class="purchase-way__text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nec molestie tellus. Nam et neque a lectus vestibulum porttitor quis non nunc. Aenean luctus eu lorem id lobortis. Integer a tortor orci. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit. Pellentesque ac est vel eros facilisis feugiat. Donec ornare ligula non fringilla hendrerit. In consequat faucibus ligula, ac venenatis velit dictum vitae. In in condimentum ex. Nulla lorem erat, fermentum non quam in, commodo molestie lacus.
      Praesent feugiat sit amet lectus nec mattis.
    </p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

If your `padding-left` from `li` is `50px`, you can set a `margin-left` on your nested `p` of `-50px` like I did in the example above.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to put the title of each `<li>` (the part outside the `<p>`) in a `<span>` or other tag, and give it a separate style with padding-left:50px.  Like so:

```
<li class="purchase-way__item">
  <span class="purchase-way__header">HEADER</span>
  <p class="purchase-way__text">PARAGRAPH HERE</p>
</li>
```

where "purchase-way__header" has the padding-left:50px attribute, and "purchase-way__item" does not.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the first line the span tag, then give padding–left to span

Answer (score 1):

You can add `margin-left: -50px;` to `.purchase-way__text` (= your p-tag)

This will move the paragraph to the left by 50px. (Since `p` is a child element of `li`, you can't "remove" the padding for it.)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eeedckk4/